# User defined Extension of C++ file for g++ compilation

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.9

For some reason, I would like to use an extension `.cxy` to use as a c++ source code. Say, the filename is `abc.cxy`. But, my `g++` (4.9.2 version) is failing to compile.
I am compiling as:

```
g++ -o abc.oxy abc.cxy
```

It's complaining as: `g++: warning: conn.cxy: linker input file unused because linking not done`
And, the object file `abc.oxy` is not being made.
Whereas, if I have the extension as `.cxx`, and compile as:

```
g++ -o abc.oxy abc.cxx
```

It's making `abc.oxy`
Am I not allowed to use extension other than `.c, .cpp, .cxx`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `g++ -o abc.oxy -x c++ abc.cxy`

`g++` can't deduce the correct language from your custom suffix, and anything that it can't deduce as source, it passes directly to the linker as an object file.

> Am I not allowed to use extension other than `.c, .cpp, .cxx`?

Not if you want GCC to auto deduce the source language. Conventions are in place so we won't have to be explicit, but you can still use the `-x` option.